# How can I initialize array of structs to global in c?

Tags: c

> I want to make struct global I tried something but I got an error.

```
struct data{
    int barcode;
    char product_name[50];
    char category[50];
    float price;
};

void printer(){
    struct data *data1=(struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
}

int main()
{
    struct data *data1=(struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    return 0;
}
```

> "error:initializer element is not constant"

```
struct data{
    int barcode;
    char product_name[50];
    char category[50];
    float price;
};
struct data *data1=(struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
```

Comment: If it's going to be a global object, why do you want to `malloc` it? You can just make it static, and then there's no problem.

Comment: You want to define or initialize global array of structs?

Comment: How can I use define and static for this code. I'm new for c programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `malloc` outside a function context. If you want a single structure, declare it as a global variable. If you want multiple structures, make an array.

```
struct data data1;
struct data dataN[12];
```